# The meaning of "heralded photon"

Tags: photons, terminology

I am not a native English speaker, and I have just started to study physics in English. However, I came across the term ***heralded photon*** while I was reading a review article about optical quantum memory. I don't understand what it means. A dictionary explains herald as, "to be a sign that something is going to happen," but it does not make any sense. Below is the excerpt from the article:

> If a single-photon detector is placed in one of the emission channels of non-degenerate spontaneous parametric down-conversion, a detection event indicates emission of a photon pair, and thus the presence of a single photon in the other channel. Such a ***heralded photon*** is emitted at an arbitrary time, however, making it unsuitable for many application.

Would you help me understand this term?

Answer (score 7):

Spontaneous parametric down-conversion converts a single incoming photon to two outgoing photons. I think the article is saying that that if you measure one photon coming out there must be a second photon as well. The author is referring to the second as a *heralded* photon in the sense that measurement of the first photon is a sign that the second (heralded) photon is going to be emitted.

Comment: @Sopheak: there's a [nice article on the subject here](http://phys.org/news/2013-05-lab-heralded-photons.html)